# How to separate, tag and transpose different pieces of text in XML with Python?

Tags: python, regex, xml, nlp

Disclaimer: I am still a novice when it comes to coding.

I am editing a lexicon using Python. Now say I have the following mark-up:

`<ab n="7" ana="lg11" lang="grk"><anchor id="lg11_7"/><link type="gnoo" targets="aGNO_25_t" n="g25_t_126_18" id="SuperfluousIdlgo_03_0004_30"><hi rend="b">25</hi>,126,18</link> (häufig verneint:) nicht erlauben, nicht gestatten: οὐκ ἐᾷ κατ᾽ αὐτῶν δυναστεύειν μέχρι ϑανάτου τὴν νόσον</ab>`

I need to separate out the German text from the Greek, and put it in its own `<ab>` tag. Then I need to have the German text in front of the locus and the Greek text. How do I accomplish this? I have searched on Regex and ElementTree but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: can you provide an example of desired output?

Comment: Something like this, I think:


`<ab n=”7” lang=”ger”>(häufig verneint:) nicht erlauben, nicht gestatten: </ab><ab n="7" ana="lg11" lang="grk"><anchor id="lg11_7"/><link type="gnoo" targets="aGNO_25_t" n="g25_t_126_18" id="SuperfluousIdlgo_03_0004_30"><hi rend="b">25</hi>,126,18</link> οὐκ ἐᾷ κατ᾽ αὐτῶν δυναστεύειν μέχρι ϑανάτου τὴν νόσον</ab>`


Of course we'd have to fix the anchoring and numbering.

Comment: You have a general problem, as you have no markup separating german from greek! [Simmias](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5636926/simmias) mentiones a procedure that would probably work for this case, but how would you handle languages that use same character sets, i.e. german and english?

Comment: Yes this is my problem. Right now this typesetting is making the lexicon unreadable since the German ends up behind the locus and thus appears to refer to the following locus instead of the preceding. 

I don't know how I would handle languages with the same character set, to be honest, that is the whole problem in sorting this out.

Comment: Google: `word level language identification`

Answer (score 0):

```
Define Greek letters in a list. 
Find first Greek letter in the lexicon entry.
Split the lexicon entry with string.split(position or letter)
Split the lexicon entry at the first '<' afterwards (i.e in </ab>)
Split the lexicon entry at the first '>' beforehand (i.e. in </link>)
Insert your new tag names.
Put the different strings together.
```

This won't be the nicest but a very easy solution.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this.

Comment: Perhaps the best assumption would be to split on last occurence of ":" instead of first greek character.   using `rfind`and the split by substring. This is perhaps more robust in terms of languages where the letters are not so easily seperated. Or, one could count ":" and always split at `the middle one +1`

Comment: @Henrik. this was our idea as well. The Greek and German are often separated by ':', '-', ')', etc.

Comment: How would you suggest I insert these tag names? ElementTree does not seem adequate for my needs, I'm trying with Regex but I'm having trouble with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657341/how-do-i-append-new-data-to-existing-xml-using-python-elementtree ElementTree does this perfectly fine..